# Add domain to office365 distribution groups that are missing it

Tags: powershell, office365

So I am trying to find a way to script adding additional domains to distribution groups that are missing it.

When I run the following

```
Get-DistributionGroup | Where {$_.emailaddresses –like "*newdomain.com*"} | FT -Property Name,Alias,EmailAddresses -Autosize
```

I get only the groups that have it.

When I run

```
Get-DistributionGroup | Where {$_.emailaddresses –notlike "*newdomain.com*"} | FT -Property Name,Alias,EmailAddresses -Autosize
```

I get all groups because all groups have the primary domain.

What i need to do is find the groups missing the new domain and add it to just those groups.

Something like this:

```
  $Groups = Get-DistributionGroup | Where {$_.emailaddresses –notlike "*newdomain.com*"}
    $Groups | ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_.Name
    Set-DistributionGroup $group -EmailAddresses @{add=$group + "@newdomain.com"}
```

So that my result would be groupname@newdomain.com added to only the distribution groups that are missing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you the groups:

```
$Groups = Get-DistributionGroup | Where-Object {
    ($_.emailaddresses -join "") -notmatch "newdomain\.com"
}
```

I used the `-join` operator because the `emailaddresses` property contains an array. The `-notmatch` operator here will return the distribution group object if any of the values in the array do not match `newdomain\.com`. I joined all the email addresses into one string so I could apply `-notmatch` to the single string.

`-notmatch` attempts to not match against a regular expression. The `.` in a regular expression represents any character. For regex to pass it as a literal dot, you need to escape it. `\` followed by a character allows that character to literally be matched provided the combination of the `\` and the character are not already reserved.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explian the \ in the domain name?

Comment: `-notmatch` attempts to not match against a regular expression. The `.` in a regular expression represents any character. For regex to pass it as a literal dot, you need to escape it. \ followed by a character allows that character to literally be matched provided the combination of the \ and the character are not already reserved.